# Angular Datatable Server Side pagination filtering, totalrecords, data are undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I'm trying to implement Angular Datatable Server side pagination but I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

When I console the **result** in factory **all 89 records** are there, When it comes to controller and I console **result** within **filterService.execute** all records are shown. but when I console **records** which actually determines "drwa, totalrecords, filteredrecords and data" everything is undefined except draw. like this:

```
Object {draw: 1, recordsTotal: undefined, recordsFiltered: undefined, data: undefined}
```

can anyone please take a look and tell me what is it I'm doing wrong here, any help would be appreciated in advance. Thanks

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('withServerSide', ['datatables'])
.controller('withServerSideController', function WithPromiseController($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, filterService)
{
    $scope.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_officer_id', 'Id'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_officer_name', 'Name')
    ];

    $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
        .newOptions()
        .withFnServerData(serverData)
        .withDataProp('es_officers') //Tried 'data' as well
        .withOption('processing', true)
        .withOption('serverSide', true)
        .withOption('paging', true)
        // .withOption('rowCallback', rowCallback)
        .withPaginationType('numbers')
        .withDisplayLength(10)
        .withDOM('<"top">t<i"bottom"p><"clear">');

    function serverData(sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {

        //All the parameters you need is in the aoData variable
        var draw = aoData[0].value;
        var order = aoData[2].value;
        var start = aoData[3].value;
        var length = aoData[4].value;

        //Then just call your service to get the records from server side
        filterService.execute(start, length, order).then(function(result){

            console.log(result);
            var records = {
                    'draw': draw,
                    'recordsTotal': result.total,
                    'recordsFiltered': result.filtered,
                    'data': result.records  
                };
            fnCallback(records);
        });
    }
});
```

**filterService Factory:**

```
angular.module('Main_Module').factory('filterService', filterService);
filterService.$inject = ['$q', '$http']
function filterService($q, $http)
{
    var service = {
    execute: execute
    };

    return service;

        function execute(start, length, order)
        {
            var defered = $q.defer();
            //Make a request to backend api and then call defered.resolve(result);
            $http({ 
                url   : 'http://localhost:3000/api/SELECTSpecific/es_officers',
                method: 'GET'
            })
            .then(function successCallback (result) 
            {   
                console.log(result);
                defered.resolve(result);
            });
            return defered.promise;
        }
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="withServerSideController">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" align="center" datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="row-border hover">
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I've figured it out myself it can be usefull for others in future, i'm making a mistake when i'm calling my url and not sending the appropriate parameters.

**What I'm calling is:**

```
$http({ 
       url   : 'http://localhost:3000/api/SELECTSpecific/es_officers',
       method: 'GET'
     })
```

**What I should be doing is:**

```
$http({ 
     url   : 'http://localhost:3000/api/SELECTQPromise/es_officers/'+start+'/'+limit+'/'+order+'/'+search,
     method: 'GET'
     })
```

**Solution:**

I realize that I wasn't even sending the parameters which are start, limit, order, search

Comment: please eleborate the question